# How can you map only if data is not undefined?

Tags: reactjs

I have this code where I fetch an external API and map its values after the user has searched for the item. The problem is that if the user hasn't searched for the item, the data is undefined, so I get an error whenever I enter the page. I want that when I enter the page to say "none" if it is undefined and map the data otherwise.

I've done this to accomplish the goal:

```
 {typeof data === "undefined" ? "none" : data.hints.map((data) => {
        return <div key={data.id}>{data.food.label}</div>
      }) }
```

But it is not working as it renders and map my data no matter if it's undefined or not.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function DietForm() {
    const [result, setResult] = useState('')
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
    const [data, setData] = useState([])


    const handleOnInputChange = (e) => {
      setResult(e.target.value)
   }

    
    useEffect(() => {
      const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://edamam-food-and-grocery-database.p.rapidapi.com/parser',
        params: {ingr: result},
        headers: {
          'x-rapidapi-host': 'edamam-food-and-grocery-database.p.rapidapi.com',
          'x-rapidapi-key': '6bc4948226msh1716c54bf80ad8dp1c8c12jsnac7a17a9e0a6'
        }
      };
      console.log(options.params.ingr)
      axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
          setData(response.data);
          console.log(response.data)
      }).catch(function (error) {
          console.error(error);
      });
    
    }, [result])
    
    console.log(result)
    return (
        <div>
            <form class="w-full max-w-lg">
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-first-name">
        Breakfast
      </label>
      <input value={result} class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white" id="grid-first-name" type="text" onChange={handleOnInputChange} placeholder="Search" />
      {typeof data === "undefined" ? "none" : data.hints.map((data) => {
        return <div key={data.id}>{data.food.label}</div>
      }) }
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
  <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-last-name">
        Lunch
      </label>
      <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="grid-last-name" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-2">
  <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-last-name">
        Dinner
      </label>
      <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="grid-last-name" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-2">
  <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-last-name">
        Snack
      </label>
      <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="grid-last-name" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DietForm
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([])
```

You've defined `data` to be an `Array`, so if `data` is still an Array, you can easily render using `map`

```js
{
  data && data.map(x => <div>{x.title}</div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `optional chaining` to check like this:

```
{
  data?.hints?.length > 0
    ? data.hints.map((data) => {
        return <div key={data.id}>{data.food.label}</div>;
      })
    : "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must also check for the other item if its undefined or not,

```js
data === undefined || data.hints == undefined || data.hints.length === 0 ? "none" : data.hints.map((data)
```

You could use some syntactical sugar to make the check more elegant. But the idea is same.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is to use optional chaining like below,

```
  {data?.hints?.map((data) => <div key={data.id}>{data.food.label}</div>) || 'none'}
```